# Nuget package readme.txt is not being updated

Tags: nuget-package, readme

I followed the steps to create and publish a nuget package including a readme.txt. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-visual-studio?tabs=netcore-cli)

The initial version of the readme.txt correctly opens when the package is installed.  But, I made changes to the readme.txt, re-packed it, re-added it to my local nuget feed (I deleted the previous), and when I install it, it opens the initial version of the readme.txt.  My changes are not in it.

The dates of the package are updated in both my bin\Release and C:\LocalNugetPackageFeed\packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, I was thinking the issue was that my package was not grabbing the latest version of the readme.txt.  Here, it's because my package was being cached.  To fix the issue, I went to Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > General > Clear All NuGet Cache(s).

[image: Screenshot of Clear All NuGet Cache(s) button]

After doing this, my updated readme.txt would show after installing the package.